# Windows 10: Unable to connect to Windows Update

Tags: windows-update, windows-10

I recently performed a clean install of Windows 10 Enterprise. I have since been completely unable to connect to Windows Update. Every time I try I get the following error:

> There were some problems installing updates, but we'll try again later. If you keep seeing this and want to search the web or contact support for information, this may help: (0x8024a208)

A Google search, with or without that error code, reveals very little if any help. I am wondering if anyone else has come across this problem and has any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try following https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3036646 to further diagnose.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. Wish I could block Windows 10 Servers.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was resolved by actively connecting to my domain. When disconnected from the domain, Windows Update fails. When being actively connected to the domain, Windows Update succeeds.

Comment: Why are you submitting this as an answer?

Comment: Yes, I am. It did solve my problem.

Comment: Your answer is confusing.  Only describe the solution to make it less confusing

Comment: I have edited my answer to be less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your company has a [WSUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services) server set up to internally distribute updates for Microsoft products.

You can check if this is true by running `gpresult /h C:\gpresult.html` with administrator privileges in the command prompt and then searching the resulting file in your web browser for `Specify intranet Microsoft update service location` which is the group policy setting to configure a WSUS server.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did run the gpresult command as you suggested, and viewed the results. I was unable to find `Specify intranet Microsoft update service location`. Recently I had Windows 8.1 installed on the same laptop as a member of the same domain, and I was able to run windows updates while at home while not being actively connected to the domain.

Answer (score 0):

This error appears if a group policy (domain or local) is set that computer is not allowed to connect to Microsoft Update. Only internal WSUS is maybe allowed and that's why within domain you will not get an error code.

Try this:

check for MS online Update within your domain (with the additional point) and then search for updates, you will get this error code  without the additional point it will function the way it should be

Sascha

Comment: grouppolicy:      Windows Components\Windows Update\Do not connect to any Windows Update Internet locations

Comment: registry:    HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations is set to 1